# php - print_r() with an array of data

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions

Working in Joomla, I have my model and view set up, but when the page is loaded, no data appears.

Model:

```
class mlsModelmls extends JModel
{
/**
 * Gets the info
 */
function mlsdata($column)
    {
    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = "
      SELECT *
        FROM ".$db->nameQuote('#__mls')."
        WHERE ".$db->nameQuote('MSTMLSNO')." = ".$db->quote('4112065').";
    ";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $row = $db->loadRow();
    print_r($row[$column]);
    }
}
```

View:

```
class mlsViewmls extends JView
{
function mlsnum($tpl = null)
    {
    $model = &$this->getModel();
    $mlsnum = $model->mlsdata(MSTMLSNO);
    $this->assignRef( 'mlsnum', $mlsnum );

    $agentuid = $model->mlsdata(MSTLISTBRD);        
    $this->assignRef( 'agentuid', $agentuid );

    $listdt = $model->mlsdata(MSTLISTDT);       
    $this->assignRef( 'listdt', $listdt );

          /** Some more assignRef() */

    parent::display($tpl);
    }
}
```

TMPL:

```
<h2 class="price">
    <?php echo $this->mlsnum; ?>
</h2>
```

When the page is loaded, the TMPL looks fine, but no data appears for the `<?php echo $this->mlsnum; ?>` reference call.

Does each `assignRef()` need it's own function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change

```
print_r($row[$column]);
```

to this:

```
return $row[$column];
```

And this one

```
parent::display($tpl);
```

to

```
return parent::display($tpl);
```

Otherwise it's just no-result.

Comment: Sorry, place an ';' after return $row[$column]

Comment: I saw that, but then my ISP dropped and I couldn't make the edit to the comment.  Now the TMPL appears again, but there's still no data.

Comment: Ok, so when I removed `return parent::display($tpl);` and reverted it to `parent::display($tpl);`, it works!  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your `mlsdata()` method doesn't returning anything, therefore you are assigning nothing to the template variable.

Add `return $row` and remove the `print_r`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your model function to this:

```
function mlsdata($column) {

    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = " SELECT * FROM ".$db->nameQuote('#__mls')." WHERE ".$db->nameQuote('MSTMLSNO')." = ".$db->quote('4112065').";

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $row = $db->loadRow();

    return $row;
}
```